# remembering app's data after app has been closed and restarted again

Tags: android

How to remember data on android app after app has been closed?(for example: In android calculator, it remembers the numbers from previous calculations,after app has rebooted again)

Answer (score 0):

You can take benefit from SharedPrefrences
more info here : [SharedPreferences Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

I will give you a simple  example

let's say we wanna store a String result

we save it in SharedPrefs like this :

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("Result","your value").apply();
```

Next time in app restart or launch retrieve we like this :

```
String result = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("Result","defaultValue");
```

> default value is : Values to return if this preference does not exist.
>
> you can change "this" with getActivity() or getApplicationContext() in
>   some cases

**and you can of course change putString and getString with putInteger or putBoolean as you which and get them with getInteger or getfloat etc..**